# Deserialize data error using serde in Rust

Tags: rust, serde

I have three structs A, B and C that are being fed to a method `process_data()` as a list of JSON. All the three structs are serde serializable/deserializable.
They are defined below as follows:-

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct A {
  pub a: u32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct B {
  pub b: u32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct C {
  pub c: u32,
}
```

The function signature looks like this

```
fn process_data(data: String) {}
```

`data` can have any of these structs but its guaranteed that one of A, B or C will be there

```
data = "A{a: 1}" 
or data = "[A{a:1}, B{b:1}, C{c:1}]"
or data = "[B{b:1}, A{a:1}, C{c:1}]"
```

I am looking for a way to process the variable `data` through serde within `process_data`, such that I can extract the structs from the data stream.

What I have tried so far.
I tried defining a struct called Collect which holds all the structs like this:-

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Collect {
 pub a1: Option<A>
 pub b1: Option<B>,
 pub c1: Option<C>
}
```

and then process the data as follows:-

```
serde_json::from_str::<Collect>(data.as_str())
```

But the previous command throws an error. Also I am looking to preserve the order of the vector in which the data is coming

I am not sure if serde will work in this case.

Comment: Your JSONs in `data` are invalid.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Your examples of `data` are not JSON, what is that supposed to be? And the second and third examples show sequences (arrays), but `Collect` is not a sequrence, how would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you wanted the following JSON data:

```json
[{"a":1}, {"b":1}, {"c":1}]
```

So, you want to deserialize to `Vec<Collect>`:

- `{"a":1}` only contains the subfield from `struct A`, no additional wrap for `a1`. Normally you handle missing levels by tagging with `#[serde(flatten)]`
- `{"a":1}` doesn't contain the subfields from `b1` or `c1`. Normally you handle missing fields by tagging (an `Option`) with `#[serde(default)]`

It seems that the combination of the two doesn't work on deserialization.

Instead, you can deserialize to an untagged enum:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum CollectSer {
    A { a: u32 },
    B { b: u32 },
    C { c: u32 },
}
```

If you do absolutely want to use your `Collect` as is, with the `Options`, you can do that still:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Default)]
#[serde(from = "CollectSer")]
struct Collect {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub a1: Option<A>,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub b1: Option<B>,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub c1: Option<C>,
}

impl From<CollectSer> for Collect {
    fn from(cs: CollectSer) -> Self {
        match cs {
            CollectSer::A { a } => Collect {
                a1: Some(A { a }),
                ..Default::default()
            },
            CollectSer::B { b } => Collect {
                b1: Some(B { b }),
                ..Default::default()
            },
            CollectSer::C { c } => Collect {
                c1: Some(C { c }),
                ..Default::default()
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you just stick with the `enum` though, it's a lot more rustic.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=946222e428ffb12ef502b16ce9f8ca30)

(Apologies if I misguessed the structure of your data, but if so, I suppose you can at least point out the difference with this?)

Comment: Please do still fix the JSON in your question. Maybe somebody else has a brighter idea based on it.

Comment: I figured that I still might need to process the input from "[A{a:1}, B{b:1}, C{c:1}]".Like in the future I have more structs that have similar attributes like D{a: 1} then from this answer, I wont be able to identify, which struct does the attribute belong to.

Comment: Then you should remove the reference to JSON because that example isn't JSON

Comment: What data format is that even supposed to be? [RON](https://docs.rs/ron/latest/ron/)? That seems to use `()` not `{}`. Or did you maybe want `["A":{"a":1}, "B":{"b":1}, "C":{"c":1}]`